# How do I get a bash gearman worker to take arguments as stdin?

Tags: bash, shell-script, stdin

I've seen the xargs method of passing arguments into gearman, but how do I just get my script to take STDIN as the input for my gearman worker instead?

The use case here is that I have a bunch of IDs that I'd like to simply fire off as this.

```
gearman -f job 123456
gearman -f job 123457
gearman -f job 123458
gearman -f job 123459
gearman -f job 123460
```

If I could do that, then iterating over a list of id numbers would be really easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you script already uses $1 as your input and you simply want to set that to default to stdin if $1 isn't set you can set you variable in this way.

```
# Set id to first argument or stdin if that is blank
id=${1:-$(cat -)}
```

Then when you startup the worker simply do

```
gearman -w -f job script.sh
```

Then to send a task to the worker that sets var to 123456 simply do this

```
gearman -f job 123456
```